# Python library architecture with two diferent math backend, how to?

Tags: python, math, architecture, package, backend

I want to build a library in python for scientific computing. Precisely for natural coordinates mechanics. I want to think a bit before jumping into the code. This post asks for any advice, bad or good ideas. I'm not a pro in python, and I'm sure. There can be experts around.

First, I want my library to be usable with numpy (numeric computing) and casadi (symbolic computing). To be as simple as possible, I'd like the library to be loadable:

```
import my_package_numpy # option 1
import my_package_casadi # option 2
```

Second, I want each class or each function and method to work both with these two types of objects ndarrays (numpy) and MX (casadi).

```
my_var_np = np.array([2,2]) # numeric 
my var_mx = MX.sym("var",[2,1]) # symbolic

from my_package_numpy import HelloWorld # option 1
hw = HelloWorld(my_var_np)

from my_package_casadi import HelloWorld # option 2
hw = HelloWorld(my_var_mx)
```

Third, I want to be able to switch to know when the user uses one or another backend in specific methods. because maths operations may be defined differently. (Is there a global variable available to know that ?)

```
class HelloWorld:
     def __init__(value):
          self.value = value
          if numpy:
             self.transpose_value = value.transpose()
          elif casadi:
             self.transpose_value = transpose(value)
```

I know the if are not well written, I don't know where to get this value.
This library could grow fast. I want to avoid as much as possible copied code and things to be written only once.

Any help, advice, or comment, would be appreciated.

I'm trying to build a package with two math backends. And I expect it to be as simple as possible for the user. but I don't know how to build the backend

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an if condition to check the type of the value like this (if the value is a numpy array then use numpy):

```
class HelloWorld:
 def __init__(value):
      if type(value) == np.ndarray:
          numpy = True
      self.value = value
      if numpy:
         self.transpose_value = value.transpose()
      elif casadi:
         self.transpose_value = transpose(value)
```

I don't know if this is the right way, but maybe it works for you :)